# scrollable prism:PopupWindowAction

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

```
> <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True"
> CenterOverAssociatedObject="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
> ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
```

How can I make this popup scrollable ?
I have tried adding the **ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"** but it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `WindowContent` property to a `ScrollViewer` element:

```
<prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
</prism:PopupWindowAction>
```

Comment: <prism:PopupWindowAction is already within <prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding NotificationRequest, Mode=OneWay}"> therefore do I need it <ContentControl Conten {Binding NotificationRequest}

Comment: What does this has to do with your original question about the ScrollViewer?

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer and vote it up if your issue has been solved. If not, please describe what your current issue is.